# How can I add expression to if clause condition in trimpath?

Tags: javascript, open-source, web-deployment-project

I am using [trimpath library](http://www.trimpath.com/) to draw dynamic page

I try to add expression to  if clause

```
{for item in itemsObj}
 {if item_index % 4 == 3 && peopleObj.length != item_index + 1 }
     <div class="search-result-row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;">
 {/if}
{/for}
```

but the value "item_index + 1" not calculated as math expression and the result for this value is pinding string 
for example 
if item_index = 3 then the result for expression is = 31

could you please help me on this?

Comment: have you tried `(item_index + 1)`?

Comment: Yes I try this still take the result as string binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with this library.

According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplateSyntax):

> The testExpr is any valid JavaScript expression, but no close-brace
>   characters.

Which means you should be able to do this:

```
{if item_index % 4 == 3 && peopleObj.length != (parseInt(item_index, 10) + 1) }
```

Comment: @KhadijahJShtayat if this answer helped you and you think it would help future visitors with a similar problem, you should accept the answer (click the green check mark).